# Calculate the probability of picking a number smaller than $N$

Tags: probability

How to calculate the probability of picking a smaller value than $X$ within $N$ attempts. Where $0<X<2^{256}$ and $1,000,000 < N$

Each attempt got $2^{256}$ options, duplicates allowed.

This question is an analogy for calculating what are the chances of mining a bitcoin block with hash power of $N$ and difficulty $X$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking your inequalities as strict, each hash has a probability $p = \frac{X-1}{2^{256}-1}$ of being successful.  Since they're independent, the probability of being successful at least once is one minus the probability that none of them is successful, or

$$
P(\text{at least one success in $N$ tries}) = 1-(1-p)^N
$$

Comment: Check out my related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612746/adjust-the-probability-of-winning